# Mejorar expresión regular para validar decimales

Tags: regex, typescript

Tengo una expresión regular para validar un valor decimal el cual deberia permitir al usuario escribir una cantidad máxima de 7 números enteros o 7 enteros con 2 decimales, el detalle es que mi expresión me esta forzando a escribir los 7 números enteros con sus 2 decimales y lo que quiero lograr es que se pueda escribir por ejemplo **1234567.50** o **1234567**, comparto la manera en la que estoy probando la expresión

```
onChangeValue(value:any){
    console.log(value.match(/^(\d{0,7})(\.\d{1,2})$/));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITADO: Gracias a @Julio por señalar un problema en la expresión.

La expresión regular que buscas es:

```
exp_regular = /^(\d{1,7})(\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/
```

Las llaves hacen coincidir la parte decimal una o ninguna vez.

```
> "0".match(exp_regular)
(3) ["0", "0", undefined, index: 0, input: "0", groups: undefined]

> "0.1".match(exp_regular)
(3) ["0.1", "0", ".1", index: 0, input: "0.1", groups: undefined]

> "1234567.89".match(exp_regular)
(3) ["1234567.89", "1234567", ".89", index: 0, input: "1234567.89", groups: undefined]

> "12345678.90".match(exp_regular)
null

> "12345678.90.90".match(exp_regular)
null

> "1234567.901".match(exp_regular)
null
```

Lo único que tienes que tener en cuenta con esa expresión regular es que el segundo grupo de coincidencia lleva el punto decimal. Puedes arreglarlo con otra expresión ligeramente cambiada y entonces quedarte con primer y tercer grupos:

```
> exp_regular2 = /^(\d{1,7})(\.(\d{1,2})){0,1}$/

> "1234567.90".match(exp_regular)
(3) ["1234567.90", "1234567", ".90", index: 0, input: "1234567.90", groups: undefined]

> "1234567.90".match(exp_regular2)
(4) ["1234567.90", "1234567", ".90", "90", index: 0, input: "1234567.90", groups: undefined]

> "1234567.90".match(exp_regular)[2]
".90"

> "1234567.90".match(exp_regular2)[3]
"90"
```

Comment: Buenas! Esto validaría `123.50.50`, que es incorrecto

Comment: Se te agradece la ayuda pero es correcto lo que comenta @Julio, se resolvió con la siguiente expresión **/^((\d{1,7})|(\d{1,7}?\.\d{1,2}))$/**

Comment: ¡Ouch! Cierto, qué despiste...pero puedo arreglarlo con una expresión más simple que la propuesta. :-) */^(\d{1,7})(\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/*

Comment: También puedes cambiar el `{0,1}` por `?`, es equivalente. No hace falta que me des las gracias en la respuesta. Para que la respuesta quede más limpia, puedes quitar la nota de agradecimiento. Pero se agradecen tus gracias :-)